# Fortran producing the incorrect answer at the first calculation

Tags: math, fortran, gfortran

Here is the fortran code I have written in part.

```c
thf(i) = ths(i)*(psi(i)/3.364)**kappa(i)
write(*,*) 'first calculation'
write(*,*) thF(i),ths(i),psi(i),kappa(i)
thf(i)=ths(i)*(psi(i)/3.364)**kappa(i)
write(*,*) 'second calculation'
write(*,*) thF(i),ths(i),psi(i),kappa(i)
```

i have predifined the variables

```c
INTEGER, PUBLIC, PARAMETER :: KR = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(r=50, p=20) !Accuracy of Real Number.
INTEGER, PUBLIC, PARAMETER :: UNmatD=10        ! Max numbers of soil materials (Vertical)
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: ths
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: thf          ! Field capacity.
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: thw          ! Wilting point.
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: psi          ! cosby psi 
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: kappa          ! cosby kappa
```

the output is as follows

```bash
 first calculation
  0.000000000000000000000000000000000E+0000
  0.445000000000000000000000000000000
  0.354000000000000000000000000000000
  0.152000000000000000000000000000000
 second calculation
  0.316028605761217751511299664240076
  0.445000000000000000000000000000000
  0.354000000000000000000000000000000
  0.152000000000000000000000000000000
```

the `thf` value via the first calculation should have been the same as that via the second calculation, since the two calculations are the same.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something that I do not know?

I read these varaibles in a line of a text file

```bash
thr ths Alfa    n   Ks   k t psi kappa  sp(1:4)
0.065   0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9 -0.2 0.354 0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
```

the whole code read this file is as follows

```c
    DO i=1,NMat
    READ(33,*) (Par(j,i),j=1,Npar),psi(i),kappa(i),(sp(j,i),j=1,4)
    
    ths(i)=par(2,i)
    thf(i)=ths(i)*(psi(i)/3.364_kr)**kappa(i)
    write(*,*) 'first calculation'
    write(*,*) thF(i),ths(i),psi(i),kappa(i)
    thf(i)=ths(i)*(psi(i)/3.364_kr)**kappa(i)
    write(*,*) 'second calculation'
    write(*,*) thF(i),ths(i),psi(i),kappa(i)
    thw(i)=ths(i)*(psi(i)/152.9_kr)**kappa(i)
    write(*,*) thF(i),thW(i),ths(i),psi(i),kappa(i)
    par(1,i)=thW(i) !pjli 20220927 thr=thw
    par(4,i) = par(4,i)*tConv/xConv
    ENDDO
```

where `Nmat=1` and `Npar=7` here, and `33` is predefined as

```c
OPEN(33,file=trim(iof)//'/rh1d.in/selector.in', status='old')
```

I have run the similar code in an independent program and the similar situation does not occur. I am very confused about it since I just simply sampled it from the original whole program.

The independent program are as follows,

```c
!  demo.f90 
!
!  FUNCTIONS:
!  demo - Entry point of console application.
!

!****************************************************************************
!
!  PROGRAM: demo
!
!  PURPOSE:  Entry point for the console application.
!
!****************************************************************************

    program demo

    implicit none

    ! Variables

    ! Body of demo
    
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: KR = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(r=50, p=20)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: KI = SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: UNmatD=10        
    REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: ths
    REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: thf          
    REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: thw          
    REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: psi          
    REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: kappa
    INTEGER (KIND=KI) :: i
    
    i=1
    ths(i)=0.445
    psi(i)=0.354
    kappa(i)=0.152
    
    thf(i) = ths(i)*(psi(i)/3.3)**kappa(i)
    write(*,*) 'first calculation'
    write(*,*) thf(i),ths(i),psi(i),kappa(i)
    thf(i)=ths(i)*(psi(i)/3.3)**kappa(i)
    write(*,*) 'second calculation'
    write(*,*) thf(i),ths(i),psi(i),kappa(i)
    
    PAUSE

    end program demo
```

its output is as follows,

```bash
 first calculation
  0.316952649895250622789373894133011
  0.444999992847442626953125000000000
  0.354000002145767211914062500000000
  0.151999995112419128417968750000000
 second calculation
  0.316952649895250622789373894133011
  0.444999992847442626953125000000000
  0.354000002145767211914062500000000
  0.151999995112419128417968750000000
Fortran Pause - Enter command<CR> or <CR> to continue.
```

Comment: Try casting your real numbers e.g. `3.364` to kind `KR` like so `3.364_kr`. If that doesn't work provide your compile instructions and ideally some inputs for us to reproduce.

Comment: I have tried it based on your suggestion. However, the same problem occured.

Comment: Thanks  for your help! I have added more details. Do you need any further information?

Comment: Please make your example a complete MWE i.e. a minimal working example and not just some snippets.

Comment: I agree, we should be able to test the code. Please prepare a small program that can be compiled and shows the program.

Comment: A summary paragraph describing what you're trying to do would help.  Bad to assume that everyone can glean your problem from looking at FORTRAN code.  You also fail to state what you think the correct answer should look like.  Poor question, poor code.  No wonder you're having problems.

Comment: Out of sanity check (I know Fortran is case insensitive) try to be consistent between `thF` and `thf`.

Comment: Put the calculations in a function with `intent(in)` arguments to make sure you don't have any unintended side effects.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and critical comments all! I have made a simple and independent program. However, i am confused that the similar issue does not happen.

Comment: We need a program that shows the issue - all we can say so far is something is different between the complete code you show and the one that contains the fragments you also present. But you are the only one who has all the data, you haven't presented us yet with anything very helpful in diagnosing it.

Comment: Are you sure the first `thf(i) = ths(i)*(psi(i)/3.364)**kappa(i)` executes? If it didn't then it will explain the `0.0e+0` output. Is there a way you can step through the code and check step by step what is happening? Your minimal code does not reproduce the issue, and it is little help right now.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to produce the output is by calling the write function before the calculation.

I can produce the following output

```text
 inputs
  0.000000000000000000000000000000000E+0000
  0.445000000000000000000000000000000
  0.354000000000000000000000000000000
  0.152000000000000000000000000000000
 calculation
  0.316028606932367769601691897176716
  0.445000000000000000000000000000000
  0.354000000000000000000000000000000
  0.152000000000000000000000000000000
```

If in my code I produce the output before the first calculation. I have also moved the calculation into a function in order to make sure there are no side effects.

#### Console.f90

Here is the skeleton code I have to try out your issue.

```fortran
program demo
implicit none

! Variables

! Body of demo

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: KR = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(r=50, p=20)
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: KI = SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: UNmatD=10        
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: Npar = 7
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(Npar, UnmatD) :: Par
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: ths
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: thf          
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: thr
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: psi          
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(UnmatD) :: kappa
REAL (KIND=KR), DIMENSION(4, UnmatD) :: sp
INTEGER (KIND=KI) :: i,j
CHARACTER(LEN=255) :: head
    
OPEN(33,file='data.txt', status='old')

READ(33,*) head
do i=1, UNmatD
    READ(33,*) (Par(j,i),j=1,Npar),psi(i),kappa(i),(sp(j,i),j=1,4)
    thr(i)=par(1,i)
    ths(i)=par(2,i)
end do

write(*,*) 'inputs'
do i=1, 1
    write(*,*) thf(i),ths(i),psi(i),kappa(i)
end do

thf = calc(ths,psi, kappa)

write(*,*) 'calculation'
do i=1, 1
    write(*,*) thf(i),ths(i),psi(i),kappa(i)
end do
PAUSE

contains

elemental function calc(ths,psi,kappa) result(thf)
real(kind=kr), intent(in) :: ths, psi, kappa
real(kind=kr) :: thf
    thf = ths*(psi/3.364_kr)**kappa
end function

end program demo
```

#### data.txt

and also with a text file containing the following 10 lines of data and 1 header.

```text
thr    ths     Alfa    n       Ks      k       t       psi     kappa   sp(1:4)
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
0.065  0.445   11.3    1.31    0.383    0.9    -0.2    0.354   0.152   0.4 0.7 0.9 1
```